# Mirroring iPhone 6s to MacBook Pro without Airplay

Tags: iphone, airplay, mirroring

I want to mirror a video-streaming app from my phone to my MacBook Pro (an app that unfortunately is not available for laptops, just iPhone and iPad). Airplay won't work for this. Need the USB port free on my computer to be able to use a projector in tandem with the phone/MacBook. I don't mind paying a few bucks for an additional app, but I need something clean and reliable that is *relatively easy* to set up for a relative computer illiterate like myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of searching, I came up with [Mirroring Assist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirroring-assist-share-your/id950117741?mt=8). Seems like a good app to use in your case.

It depends on [Mirroring360](http://www.mirroring360.com/) software installed on the Mac/PC (7 days trial, full-featured) or an Apple TV.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't understand. The title of this thread says "Mirroring iPhone 6s to MacBook Pro ***without Airplay***". I tried both MirroringAssist and Mirroring360 - they both require the use of Airplay :(